# Moving DocumentDB to another location

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am having performance issues with a DocumentDB hosted in the East.  Our other resources are located in North Central and would like to test if moving our DocumentDB to the new North location makes a difference.

How do you move a DocumentDB to another location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the DocumentDB migration tool. You can find information about it here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-import-data/

Look for the section on migrating your data between two collections. I assume they can be in different data centers. If not, then you may need to use the tool to download it to a JSON file and then use the tool again to upload it to the new location.